# How can I npm link a local package in a monorepo to another application?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, npm, npm-link

So I've been at this for a while, I have a npm workspace with a my packages (a monorepo basically) and I am trying to link a ui library I'm working on (the library is using react) so that I can use it on another application (react as well). When I do the linking the library folder does show under my *node_modules* folder in my main application but it still gets an error, I've been looking at other answers but I haven't found one that quite fits my problem.

This is the error that I currently get:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'ui'. 'C:/Users/.../Documents/.../.../packages/ui/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

*package.json* for the library I'm linking

```
{
  "name": "ui",
  "private": true,
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.6.3",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2 || ^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2 || ^18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.4.5",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "^3.5.3"
  },
  "main": "./lib/index.js",
  "module": "dist/ptr-ui.es.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/ptr-ui.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/ptr-ui.umd.js",
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.10.3"
  }
}
```

*package.json* for the main project where I am trying to use the linked library

```
{
  "name": "client-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/md5": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "merge": "^1.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.2",
    "node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.26.5",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
    "print-js": "^1.6.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-json-pretty": "^2.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.7.1",
    "ui": "1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^17.0.5",
    "react-app-env": "^1.2.3",
    "react-context-devtool": "^2.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

I've tried a lot of things but I just can't find a solution, let me know if there are any other files that might give more context as to what could be going wrong. Also both projects are using the same node version

Comment: In your main project, add a declaration file like, ```ui.d.ts```. In that add a declaration like ```declare module 'ui';```. Preferably add it in root directory of project

Comment: what content would go here if all I'm trying to access from my main application would be components in the ui library? after `declare module 'ui' {}`

Comment: No, just this -> ```declare module 'ui';```. Also, once added, include the typings in your ```package.json```, so that the declaration is considered. If you are worried about the ```implicitly has any type``` issue, either use ```"noImplicitAny": true``` in tsconfig.json or add type definitions in ui.d.ts file for the respective code that has ```any``` type.